# Matlab recursive curve fitting with custom equations

Tags: matlab, recursion, curve-fitting

I have a curve `IxV`. I also have an equation that I want to fit in this `IxV` curve, so I can adjust its constants. It is given by:

`I = I01(exp((V-R*I)/(n1*vth))-1)+I02(exp((V-R*I)/(n2*vth))-1)`

`vth` and `R` are constants already known, so I only want to achieve `I01`, `I02`, `n1`, `n2`. The problem is: as you can see, I is dependent on itself. I was trying to use the curve fitting toolbox, but it doesn't seem to work on recursive equations.

Is there a way to make the curve fitting toolbox work on this? And if there isn't, what can I do?

Comment: Are `I01` and `I02` functions, or did you leave out a `*`?

Comment: Why you just do not try Gradient Descent Algorithm or Least-squared Method?

Answer (score 0):

No, the CFTB cannot fit such recursively defined functions. And errors in I, since the true value of I is unknown for any point, will create a kind of errors in variables problem. All you have are the "measured" values for I.

The problem of errors in I MAY be serious, since any errors in I, or lack of fit, noise, model problems, etc., will be used in the expression itself. Then you exponentiate these inaccurate values, potentially casing a mess.

You may be able to use an iterative approach. Thus something like

```
% 0. Initialize I_pred
I_pred = I;

% 1. Estimate the values of your coefficients, for this model:
% (The curve fitting toolbox CAN solve this problem, given I_pred)
I = I01(exp((V-R*I_pred)/(n1*vth))-1)+I02(exp((V-R*I_pred)/(n2*vth))-1)

% 2. Generate new predictions for I_pred
I_pred = I01(exp((V-R*I_pred)/(n1*vth))-1)+I02(exp((V-R*I_pred)/(n2*vth))-1)

% Repeat steps 1 and 2 until the parameters from the CFTB stabilize.
```

The above pseudo-code will work only if your starting values are good, and there are not large errors/noise in the model/data. Even on a good day, the above approach may not converge well. But I see little hope otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `I01` and `I02` are variables and not functions, then you should set the problem up like this:

```
a0 = [I01 I02 n1 n2];
MinFun = @(a) abs(a(1)*(exp(V-R*I)/(a(3)*vth))-1) + a(2)*(exp((V-R*I)/a(4)*vth))-1) - I);

aout = fminsearch(a0,MinFun);
```

By subtracting I and taking the absolute value, the point where both sides are equal will be the point where `MinFun` is zero (minimized).

Comment: As I pointed out, since the values of I are used in the expression, any errors/noise/lack of fit in them will potentially be a problem. It  may be especially bad since exponentials are then applied to the result. This will NOT be a least squares solution.

Comment: That's why I subtracted `I` from both sides.  You are trying to find the values of the adjustable parameters that make both sides of the equation equal.  Subtracting `I` from both sides and finding the values for which the result equals zero is mathematically equivalent to finding the values that make both sides equal, recursive or not.  Taking the absolute value turns it into a minimization problem by making 0 the minimum point.  Since there is noise in the data, your result will not be exactly 0, but it will be as close as possible.

Comment: SIGH. NO. Subtracting I from both sides does nothing. The expression still has I buried inside it. So any noise in I will STILL be exponentiated, and still potentially be a problem.

Comment: The Taylor expansion of an exponential `a*exp(b*x+c)` around the point x is `a*exp(b*x+c)+ a*b*exp(b*x+c)*(dx-x)` for small values of `dx`.  In your case, `a=I01`, `b=-(R/(n1*vth))`, and `c=(V/(n1*vth)-1)`.  So as long as `abs(b)` is order 1 or less and the relative size of `dx` is small with respect to `x`, then the error terms will be of similar magnitude on each side of the equation and, more importantly, *linear*.

Comment: As long as abs(b), etc... My point is, you have NO idea what size b is, nor what size are the errors/residuals. We have been given no information on that matter. These facts are extremely pertinent, and should NOT be blithely ignored.

Comment: If the noise in your data is so large that it is not in this regime, then you have little hope of extracting meaningful parameters from your fit, however you do it.  If the noise is so large it is more than a perturbation on the underlying "true" values and you have to move on to the higher orders in the Taylor expansion, then it's time to go back into the lab and get more data.  As for the size of `b`, it is still just a linear scaling factor in the neighborhood of `x`.